# Why is My Program Only Sometimes Correctly Identifying the Highest and Lowest Values in an Array?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, for-loop, math

I am writing a homework program which, among other things, must be able to output the highest and lowest values in an array. The ten numerical values in this array, referred to as scores int he context of the program are inputted by the user early on. I have two functions which calculate the highest and lowest value int he array respectively. For reasons I cannot figure out, the getHighScore function only sometimes correctly determines the largest value depending on what values have been stored int he array and the value returned by the getLowScore function always determines that the lowest number is the same one that is returned by getHighScore.

I have already tried comparing my code to other code both from my own past programs and online that is meant to serve the same purpose, and although it was nearly identical to one such example, my getLowScore function still never works as intended. I believe it also worth including the function in my program which calculates the average of the array's contents below, as although it uses different commands, it always works as intended and I am not sure what sets it apart from the other two functions.

```
//Stores the highest score in the array in the "highest" variable
int getHighScore (/*in*/const int somearray[], /*in*/int size)
//PRE: The contents of the array have been defined, as well as the 
//variable "size"
//POST: The largest value in the array is stored in the "highest" variable
{
    int highest = 0;

    highest = somearray [0]; //Set highest to the first element in the array
    for (int index = 1; index < size; index++)
    {
        if (somearray [index] > highest);
            highest = somearray [index];
    }

    return highest;
}

//Stores the lowest score in the array in the "lowest" variable
int getLowScore (/*in*/const int somearray[], /*in*/int size)
//PRE: The contents of the array have been defined, as well as the 
//variable "size"
//POST: The lowest value in the array is stored in the "lowest" variable
{
    int lowest = 0;

    lowest = somearray [0]; //Set lowest to the first element in the array
    for (int index = 1; index < size; index++)
    {
        if (somearray [index] < lowest);
            lowest = somearray [index];//
    }

    return lowest;
}

//Stores the mean of all the values in the array in the "average" variable
int getAvgScore (/*in*/const int somearray[], /*in*/int size)
//PRE: The contents of the array have been defined, as well as the 
//variable "size"
//POST: The average value in the array is stored in the "average" variable
{
    int totalScore = 0;
    double average = 0;

    //average = somearray [0]; //Set highest to the first element in the 
array
    for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
    {
        totalScore += somearray [index];
    }

    average = totalScore / 10;

    return average;
}
```

This code compiles, but logic errors prevent me from achieving the desired outcome.

Comment: Hint: `if` statements don't normally end in a semicolon.

Comment: Hint #2: Use a visual editor that auto-indents. We now have technical crutches that save us from certain errors.

Answer (score 3):

It's these lines right here:

```
if (somearray [index] > highest);
            highest = somearray [index];
```

Should be something like this instead:

```
if (somearray [index] > highest) {
            highest = somearray [index];
}
```

Note: You may or may not be making the same mistake more than once, so I'd double check if I were you.

Answer (score 1):

I think @Chipster's answer is correctly, another suggestion to avoid that kinds of error is treat your compile warning as error.

Because if you check you compile warning carefully, you will find at least one warning(I'm use clang)

```
warning: if statement has empty body [-Wempty-body]
    if (somearray [index] > highest);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only issues I can see with your getLowScore/getHighScore methods is that they may go very wrong if the size is zero. Otherwise, there are no problems there. Without any additional context provided as to where & how those methods are used, it's not possible to help much further sadly.

Only other issue I can see in the getAvgScore method is that you want to append .0 to the 10 here:

```
average = totalScore / 10.0;
```

(otherwise the average can only ever end up being a whole number). Also, would it be sensible to return a double from getAvgScore? If thats cast to an int where its used, so be it. But at least you are returning the additional digits to the right of the decimal place in case you need them.

Comment: You don't see anything odd about the `if` statements in those two functions?